# Passing a malloc'd char * into constructor, using printf on the char * gives segmentation fault

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char, c-strings

I have a main function which calls this:

```
int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
    char * x = (char*) malloc(100);
    x = "test string";
    printf("data: %s", x);
    StreamManager * SM = new StreamManager(NULL, x);
}
```

StreamManager has a constructor here:

```
StreamManager::StreamManager(ConnectionManager * CMin, char * data) {
    printf("Creating StreamManager\n");
    printf("%s\n", data);
    printf("done");

    ...
}
```

Calling this gives the output:

```
data: test stringCreating StreamManager
test string
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Why?  Shouldn't it be null terminated?

EDIT:  Problem persists even after changes.

**MAIN:**

```
char * x = (char*) malloc(100);
strcpy(x, "This is a test");
StreamManager * SM = new StreamManager(NULL, x);
```

**CONSTRUCTOR:**

```
printf("Creating StreamManager\n");
printf("%s\n", data);
printf("done");
fflush(stdout);
```

Done doesn't print.  The segfault I think is happening in the second printf in the constructor.

Comment: why what? what are you asking exactly

Comment: Why is it giving a segfault?  Shouldn't it print "done" after the "test string"?  Also, if I change the test string to "test string\0", it still has the issue.

Answer (score 5):

> Passing a malloc'd char * into constructor, using printf on the char * gives segmentation fault

You are not 'passing a `malloc`'d `char *`' into any constructor:

```
char * x = (char*) malloc(100);
```

Here you are `malloc`-ing 100 bytes and storing the address into `x.`

```
x = "test string";
```

Here you are *altering* the variable `x` to point to the literal string `"test string"`, which NB is already null-terminated. You have also caused a 100-byte memory leak at this point.

```
printf("Creating StreamManager\n");
```

Here you are successfully printing a message.

```
printf("%s\n", data);
```

Here you are successfully printing `"test string"`.

```
printf("done");
```

Here you are successfully printing `"done"`, but it may not have appeared due to `stdio` buffering.

```
...
```

Here you are doing something *else* undisclosed which is causing the core dump.

Comment: How can I make the code finish printing "done" before it moves on?  I'm trying to debug my program to make sure it works correctly, and want to know exactly when the segfault is happening.

Comment: Call `fflush(stdout);` immediately afterwards. Have you considered using a debugger? If not, why not? That's what they're for.

Comment: I will use a debugger, this is just a special case.

Comment: It's a special case on which you've wasted a significant amount of several people's time by not using a debugger.

Comment: The problem persists, by the way.  Segfault is happening in the second printf statement I think.   I can't use a debugger right now because of computer issues, and deadlines.  editted original post

Comment: The second `printf()` prints what it is supposed to print. *Ergo* it is not seg-faulting. And you will not convince me that the next one fails either. Printing the literal string `"done"` cannot possibly cause a segmentation violation, and you shouldn't be even wasting your own time let alone ours on these wild suppositions. I suggest you post more of the code if you can't use a debugger right now.

Answer (score 2):

`x = "test string";` is not copying the string into your allocated buffer, instead it is pointing `x` to the `const char*` pointing to `"test string"`.

You have to use the `strcpy(char * destination, const char * source )` function in this case like so `strcpy(x, "test string")`, that will handle the null termination part of it as well.

---

**EDIT**

From what you've posted, the SEGFAULT seems unrelated to the snippet of code you posted.